# Confused between IConsumer and Webhooks

Tags: events, webhooks, nopcommerce

I am interested in the EntityUpdated event which happens when a Product is updated...

My Aim : **when a product is updated I want to make a post to request to salesforce Api..**

But I am confused between the following two ways....

**First way** :  Make a plugin and do something like...

```
public class SfdcPlugin: BasePlugin, IConsumer<EntityUpdated<Product>>
{

    public void HandleEvent(EntityUpdated<Product> eventMessage)
    {
         // call the salesforce Api here
    }
}
```

**Second way** : ...

1. Use Nopcommerce Rest Api  and make a webhook .
2. create a serverless function on aws lamda/azure functions and shift the above code to that serverless 
   function...
3. Call that serverless function using that webhook

please guide me..... let me know which solution to follow and WHY also let me know if there is any other way out

Comment: thanks a lot Div :)

Comment: Glad I could help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's hard to say which one is best for you..as it's opinion based.
 Generally, people going for a simple way(first way) because there is no need to third party services more even nopCommerce API.

Use of AWS lamda boost performance if product update happens frequently. But I think you need go for lamda only if performance is your concern and nopCommerce default event handler is not able to handle requests. Basically admin area doesn't have that much load if you don't have lakhs of vendors managing their products

Hope this helps!